# Disable vaadin combobox dropdown

Tags: combobox, vaadin

Hi in vaadin combobox i have only one item added which is in select by default.
So now there is no need in drop down option.
Is there any way to disable dropdown option in combobox?

Regards,
Vignesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the combobox to read-only or disabled if it only has one option. combobox.setReadOnly(true) will make it look like a label while combobox.setEnabled(false) will grey it out and disable the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you want to show instead? Just a Label? Then check if the container-size you add to the combobox is 1 and show a Label with the only "option" instead.

Comment: i cant change it to label because it will alter the rest of the application .